# Using Fractal's $defaultIncludes

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to use a $defaultIncludes() and am getting an exception --

```
ErrorException in ViewoptionTransformer.php line 8:

Argument 1 passed to App\Transformers\ViewoptionTransformer::transform() must be an instance of App\Viewoption, boolean given
```

Following the tutorial (http://laravelista.com/build-an-api-with-lumen-and-fractal/) except I am using Laravel 5.1 not Lumen:

1. in User model, I have the hasOne relationship with Viewoption called viewoptions
2. In the UsersController, I eager load viewoptions

   `public function index(Manager $fractal, UserTransformer $userTransformer)
   {
       $records = User::with(['locations', 'viewoptions'])->get();
       $collection = new Collection($records, $userTransformer);
       $data = $fractal->createData($collection)->toArray();
       return $this->respondWithCORS($data);
   }`
3. In the UserTransformer, I have the $defaultInclude and the includes method

`protected $defaultIncludes = ['viewoptions'];`

```
`public function transform(User $user)
{
    return [
        'id' => $user->id,
        'name' => $user->name,
        'is_active' => (boolean)$user->is_active,
        'is_admin' => (boolean)$user->is_admin,
        'is_manager' => (boolean)$user->is_manager,
        'role_id' => (integer) $user->role_id,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'phone' => $user->phone,
        'full_sidebar' => (boolean)$user->full_sidebar
    ];
}

public function includeViewoptions(User $user)
{
    $viewoptions = $user->viewoptions;
    return $this->collection($viewoptions, new ViewoptionTransformer);
}`
```

4. Have a ViewoptionTransformer

   `

   ```
   use App\Viewoption;
   use League\Fractal\Resource\Collection;
   use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

   class ViewoptionTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {
       public function transform(Viewoption $item)
       {
           //return $item;

           return [
               'id' => $item->id,
               'user_id' => $item->user_id,
               'voAgency' => (boolean)$item->voAgency,
               'voBalanceDue' => (boolean)$item->voBalanceDue,
               'voCloseDate' => (boolean)$item->voCloseDate,
               'voCommitTotal' => (boolean)$item->voCommitTotal,
               'voDistributor' => (boolean)$item->voDistributor,
               'voDueDate' => (boolean)$item->voDueDate,
               'voFeePercentage' => (boolean)$item->voFeePercentage,
               'voRegion' => (boolean)$item->voRegion,
               'voSeason' => (boolean)$item->voSeason,
           ];
       }
   }`
   ```

Worked with these and slight variations of these throughout the day yesterday and I can't rid myself of that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all of your `users`.`id` corresponds to some `viewoptions`.`user_id`.
Just check it:

```
$records = User::with(['locations', 'viewoptions'])->get();
dd($records);
```

some viewoptions will be **null** or **false** or just undefined

Comment: This is a screenshot of that dieAndDump (http://cl.ly/bzva) and all of the records DO have user>relations>viewoptions but I am not sure that is what you meant.

Comment: UPDATE: I removed all but one user from the seeder as well as all but one viewoptions record and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today, all my other uses of transformers had been with **hasMany** relationships. I was always instantiating the transformer with a **collection of objects**.

However, when using a transformer with a **belongsTo** relationship and instantiating the transformer with **only one object** (similar to how you are passing only one object from a hasOne relationship) I would get the same **boolean given** error.

In the end I solved the issue by using '**item**' instead of '**collection**' when instantiating the transformer.

Within your **includeViewoptions** function

**Instead** of using

`return $this->collection($viewoptions, new ViewoptionTransformer);`

**try**

`return $this->item($viewoptions, new ViewoptionTransformer);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using collection use item like so

```
    public function includeViewoptions(User $user){
        $viewoptions = $user->viewoptions;
        return $this->item($viewoptions, new ViewoptionTransformer);
    }`
```